# Trying to limit data that comes back in mysql query/array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have these two tables...

schedule (gameid, homeid, awayid, weekno, seasonno)

teams (teamid, location, nickname)

This mysql query below gets me schedule info for ALL 32 teams...

```
        $sql = "SELECT
        h.nickname AS home,
        a.nickname AS away,
        h.teamid AS homeid,
        a.teamid AS awayid,
        s.weekno
    FROM schedule s
        INNER JOIN teams h ON s.homeid = h.teamid
        LEFT JOIN teams a ON s.awayid = a.teamid
    WHERE s.seasonno =2014";
$schedule= mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
if (!$schedule) {
die("Database query failed: " . mysqli_error($connection));
} else { 
// Placeholder for data
    $data = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($schedule)) {
        if ($row['away'] == "") {$row['away']="BYE";}
        $data[$row['homeid']][$row['weekno']] = $row['away'];
        $data[$row['awayid']][$row['weekno']] = '@ '.$row['home'];
    }
}
```

However, I only want to get info for one specific team, which is stored in the $teamid variable. This should be very easy, right?  I have tried multiple things, including this one below (where I added an AND statement), but this one still outputs too much...

```
$sql = "SELECT
    h.nickname AS home,
    a.nickname AS away,
    h.teamid AS homeid,
    a.teamid AS awayid,
    s.weekno
FROM schedule s
    INNER JOIN teams h ON s.homeid = h.teamid 
    LEFT JOIN teams a ON s.awayid = a.teamid 
WHERE s.seasonno =2014
AND h.teamid=$teamid OR a.teamid=$teamid";
$schedule= mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
if (!$schedule) {
die("Database query failed: " . mysqli_error($connection));
} else { 
// Placeholder for data
    $data = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($schedule)) {
        if ($row['away'] == "") {$row['away']="BYE";}
        $data[$row['homeid']][$row['weekno']] = $row['away'];
        $data[$row['awayid']][$row['weekno']] = '@ '.$row['home'];
    }
}
```

Below is the array that the above outputs.  It's better, but all I want is that 2nd array ([1]) which has, in this example, the Eagles full schedule.  It's not giving me too much else and I guess I could live with it and just ignore the other stuff, but I'd rather be as efficient as possible and only get what I need...

```
Array
(
    [24] => Array
        (
            [1] => Eagles
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => Jaguars
            [3] => Redskins
            [5] => Rams
            [9] => @ Texans
            [11] => @ Packers
            [13] => @ Cowboys
            [14] => Seahawks
            [17] => @ Giants
            [4] => @ 49ers
            [6] => Giants
            [10] => Panthers
            [15] => Cowboys
            [2] => @ Colts
            [7] => BYE
            [8] => @ Cardinals
            [12] => Titans
            [16] => @ Redskins
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [3] => Eagles
            [8] => Eagles
        )

    [23] => Array
        (
            [5] => Eagles
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [9] => Eagles
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [11] => Eagles
            [1] => Eagles
            [3] => @ Eagles
            [16] => Eagles
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [13] => Eagles
            [17] => Eagles
            [15] => @ Eagles
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [14] => Eagles
            [6] => Eagles
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [17] => Eagles
            [5] => Eagles
            [6] => @ Eagles
        )

    [29] => Array
        (
            [4] => Eagles
        )

    [31] => Array
        (
            [9] => Eagles
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [10] => Eagles
            [11] => Eagles
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [15] => Eagles
        )

    [27] => Array
        (
            [1] => @ Eagles
        )

    [28] => Array
        (
            [2] => Eagles
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [4] => Eagles
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [5] => @ Eagles
        )

    [] => Array
        (
            [7] => @ Eagles
        )

    [25] => Array
        (
            [9] => Eagles
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [10] => @ Eagles
        )

    [26] => Array
        (
            [12] => @ Eagles
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [14] => @ Eagles
        )

)
```

UPDATE:  I added parentheses per Abhik (thanks!) and it helped a little, but is still giving too much, i.e...

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => Jaguars
            [2] => @ Colts
            [3] => Redskins
            [4] => @ 49ers
            [5] => Rams
            [6] => Giants
            [7] => BYE
            [8] => @ Cardinals
            [9] => @ Texans
            [10] => Panthers
            [11] => @ Packers
            [12] => Titans
            [13] => @ Cowboys
            [14] => Seahawks
            [15] => Cowboys
            [16] => @ Redskins
            [17] => @ Giants
        )

    [27] => Array
        (
            [1] => @ Eagles
        )

    [28] => Array
        (
            [2] => Eagles
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [3] => @ Eagles
            [16] => Eagles
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [4] => Eagles
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [5] => @ Eagles
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [6] => @ Eagles
            [17] => Eagles
        )

    [] => Array
        (
            [7] => @ Eagles
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [8] => Eagles
        )

    [25] => Array
        (
            [9] => Eagles
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [10] => @ Eagles
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [11] => Eagles
        )

    [26] => Array
        (
            [12] => @ Eagles
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [13] => Eagles
            [15] => @ Eagles
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [14] => @ Eagles
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use parentheses for separating the conditions

```
WHERE s.seasonno =2014
AND h.teamid=$teamid OR a.teamid=$teamid
```

to

```
WHERE 
s.seasonno =2014
AND 
(h.teamid=$teamid OR a.teamid=$teamid)
```

Answer (score 0):

OR's are slowing down queries, you could use:

```
 ... WHERE s.seasonno =2014 AND $teamid IN (h.teamid, a.teamid)
```

or

```
 ... WHERE s.seasonno=2014 AND $teamid IN (s.homeid, s.awayid)
```